# Multiple Angular micro applications combined in one application

Tags: angular

I found this tutorial:
https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527
This is about combining multiple Angular applications into single one..

But I have a question, if this is even possible what I want.
I want to create angular project. In this project I want comopnents like CV builder, poll, forum.
All these micro apps (CV builder, poll, formu,..) work together as one project in port 4200..
Is there an option, to make possible that I can even run my CV builder by its own on 4201 and maybe poll on 4202 but also everything together on 4200?
(General idea is that if i need to repair or change something on CV builder, I can just take down CV builder without taking down the whole project or "main app).

Sorry if my question is confusing, but I need just a prototype for this.. Something like in this tutorial I posted in this question.

Comment: If you're using the angular CLI, then you can [serve](https://angular.io/cli/serve) each application on a different port.

Answer (score 1):

Like what @R.Richards said, you can serve each application on a different port but in order to tie everything together to a single port `4200`, you'll need to use something like [single-spa](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular).

Comment: So if i create project ng new prototype and then build my micro apps with ng g c cvbuilder, ng g c poll.. I can run my components which are actually my micro apps on separate ports like one on 4201 and other  on 4202 and then all of them together with ng serve? Or is this not possible

Comment: Yes, all your micro apps will be on separate ports, the single-spa documentation has good examples on how that works.

Comment: Is it also possible with that tutorial I posted in question?

Comment: Yes but that tutorial is just injecting your separate apps code into each other and is not running each app separately on a port.

Comment: But CAN I run separate applications if I want with that tutorial, or not?

Comment: Yes you can, but it won't tie together in your main port `4200`. It'll just be individual apps running on different ports.